# Merge bit variables in array in C

Tags: c, verilog, microcontroller, 8051

I'm working on 8051 micro-controller platform with KEIL as IDE and C as the programming language.

I'm trying to create array of bits for use in switch function.

```
 sbit P1;
 sbit P2;
 sbit P3;

 buttons [2:0] = P1 | P2 | P3

 switch (buttons[2:0])
  {
    case 0x1: //First button is pressed 
    case 0x2: //Second button is pressed
    case 0x4: //Third is pressed
    default: //Multiple buttons are pressed. Hence invalid

  }
```

I couldnot find a way to combine bits into a single entity and use it for switch  function.

Can anyone suggest way around to do the task in any possible method.

Comment: What's wrong with `switch(P1 << 0 | P2 << 1 | P3 << 2)`? I suppose you could force the linker into placing the individual into a contiguous byte register within the bit-addressable area but that sort of thing gets rather messy.

Comment: Thaat's not C .

Comment: @Olaf: Incidentally what level of deviation and extension from the C language is acceptable for a question to be suitably categorized under the C tag? In this case allowing access the bit-addressable memory features of the architecture is clearly an extension of the language but a relatively natural one, and in my mind not obviously much different from intrinsics, `pragma` constructs or reliance on implementation-defined behavior.

Comment: @doynax: How about reading the info page? And as you might have noticed, I did not remove the C tag. Which implementation do you knwo supporting `[2:0]` syntax? Anyway, what is your point?

Comment: @Olaf: No particular point, but the info page it doesn't seem to be explicit on this subject and I have withnesses multiple questions recently devolving into extended discussions in the presence of non-portable behavior and so I figured I might take the opportunity to hijack a thread myself to perhaps gain some enlightenment on how `C` is moderated. Anyway, no C compiler which I know of supports the `[2:0]` construct and this seems to be a syntax which the question borrows from Verilog to describe the intent but clearly not knowing how to achieve it in C. I think.

Comment: @doynax: That's not what comment at questions are for. You might want to ask on meta. But the info page is clear about what the C tag implies: the standard. And there is only one C standard. Anyway, to repeat once more: **I intentionally did not remove the C tag**.

Comment: @doynax  you are right. Syntax is of verilog type. But my intent is same as you said

Comment: @doynax but method you suggested is not working

Comment: @Vinod kumar: In what specific sense is it failing? You may need to reverse the order judging by the code, I had assumed that `P1` was the first button described in the comment.

Comment: how is this related to verilog?

Comment: @doynax How can we shift bit variable?

Comment: @Vinod kumar: I would expect a bit variable to be implicitly promoted to a full `int` when fed to the shift operator, much as a `bool` would. This certainly works in IAR though if Keil generates a compile-time error then you may try an `if` chain instead (e.g. `char sum = 0; if(P1) sum |= 1; if(P2) sum |= 2; if(P2) sum |= 4`.

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have found a way around to solve my problem.

```
int buttons=0x00;       
buttons = ((0xFF & !P1) << 2) | ((0xFF & !P2) << 1) | ((0xFF & !P3) << 0);
```